# No res folder. No activity_main.xml. No activity. No layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am just starting to use Android Studio.

I have followed the steps through in the Studio. I chose "Basic Activity". The app loads, but there's nothing but empty directories there and it has no activity folder or anything to edit the layout with.

I checked it in the Windows explorer, and it just looks the same as in Android studio.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430679/activity-main-xml-not-in-layout-folder-as-well-as-anything-else), [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor), [this](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1349), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551756/android-studio-no-main-activity-no-layouts-on-a-new-project), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268401/content-main-xml-missing), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896889/new-created-values-folder-is-not-visible-in-android-studio), and other ones, and have probably spent over an hour trying to figure out how to do this.

I've also re-tried creating the project at least 5 times, but I've had no success.

Edit: Here's what the app folder looks like:
[image]

Edit: Someone told me I should just create a new activity. Being an absolute new person, I didn't know how to do that, so I looked [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398235/how-to-create-new-activity-in-android-studio). However, the post tells me that I need to go into the "New" menu, but I don't see "Activity" in here like the post asserted it would be.

[image]

Comment: try with this link https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project. if again not success post your steps to create project

Comment: I already have. Sigh. I just read that, and it basically is just a description of what I already said I did.

Comment: I find this really strange. I recently created a new app to work with some concepts outside of my main app. When I chose Basic Activity all the files I expected were generated, classes for an activity and two fragments as well as .xml layout files for them and other resources.

Comment: I'm not saying I don't believe you. I just have no idea what would cause this. I suggest that you manually create a new Activity in your project and forge forward from there.

Comment: Alright. How do I create a new activity, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if this was what was causing it, but first I uninstalled then re-installed Android studio, deleted the old project, and created a new one.

It still didn't work, BUT I just noticed a little error log button.

You see, I named my application com.con.pfq. It wasn't liking the "con" part - said it's an invalid file name.

Sooo... I recreated the app as com.connoriscool.pfqmmobile. It liked that more.

No idea what's happening here, but that's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the following menu click the arrow and select "Project" (is better):

[image]

Then go to "name of your project folder" > "app" > "src" > "main" > "res".

Comment: I frequently switch between Project and Android views. They each have their uses depending on what you are doing.

Comment: I have already tried this. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: Can you show a picture to see what you have in the `app` folder?

Comment: @Mike087 I added it in an edit to the original post.